# Webview orientation/rotation issue with Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ios8, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

The Facebook Unity SDK webview login is stuck in portrait mode, even though my game is in landscape.
All the code is in a native library and I don't have access to change it.

The issue seems to be fixed in the Facebook iOS SDK v3.18 but not yet in the Unity SDK v6.1 Beta
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x#3_18

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or maybe a fix in the next version, if anyone at Facebook is reading this? Thank you

Also the Facebook App Login doesn't work on iOS and it always defaults to webview.
However it seems to be working perfectly on Android.

Comment: Is there any way to know which IOS SDK is included with the Facebook SDK for Unity (v6.0)

Comment: @lysergic-acid It's not in the changelog unfortunately :-( Unity SDK 5.0.3 Beta used iOS SDK to 3.11.0 but no word on 6.0 though

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in 6.2 beta SDK